Leaflet not drawing polylines
I had several apps running under Chrome on a Windows 10 PC. It stopped working so I reinstalled leaflet but it still doesn't work. Using Chrome Developer Tools, it stops in leaflet.js at
return document.namespaces.add("lvml", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"),

in
function je(t) {

It draws the map ok but won't draw polylines.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks
Re-installed leaflet. I expected that would fix whatever has gone wrong. BTW, I use xampp so the maps are locally-sourced

This was a Chrome issue. I re-downloaded Chrome and it's working ok.

This was a Chrome issue.  It only happened when Developer Tools was open, and I worked around it by black-boxing leaflet.js

Why did you post two "identical" answers?
